# How to filter data use select options on button click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with filtering data on the table.

I have in the view 4 select options, in which I have some data. I want to filter data in the table depending on the options which all ready exist.

The issue is in case I will change only one options, and push button add filter it will works fine, if i will use 2-3 options filter will not work.

HTML:

```
<select id="option1">
    <option></option>
    <option>Thulasiram.S</option>
    <option>ST Ram</option>
    <option>Ram Kumar.S</option>
    <option>Dinesh Kumar.S  </option>
</select>

<select id="option2">
    <option></option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>

<select id="option3">
    <option></option>
    <option>Chess</option>
    <option>Cricket</option>
</select>
<select id="option4">
    <option></option>
    <option>Day</option>
    <option>Month</option>
    <option>Week</option>
</select>
<button id="test213">Add filter</button>
<table id="ticketList">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="shelulerData">
        <tr>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Sport</th>
            <th>Class </th>
            <th>Term</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Day">
            <td>Thulasiram.S</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="11" data-class="1" data-term="Month">
            <td>ST Ram</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Cricket</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Month</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="21" data-class="2" data-term="Day">
            <td>Ram Kumar.S</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Day</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filter-row" data-age="30" data-class="3" data-term="Week">
            <td>Dinesh Kumar.S</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>Chess</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Week</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#test213').click(function () {
    getSelectedVal()
});


function getSelectedVal() {
    var startDate = $('#option1 option:selected').text()
    var duetDate = $('#option2 option:selected').text()
    var templateName = $('#option3 option:selected').text()
    var status = $('#option4 option:selected').text()

    filterData(startDate)
    filterData(duetDate)
    filterData(templateName)
    filterData(status)
}


function filterData(data) {
    if (data != '') {
        var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
        rows.filter(":contains('" + data + "')").show();
    }
}
```

I create jsfiddle:  [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/h1emyx83/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call filterData you are basically hiding everything.
Suggesting you when applying filter to add that filter to array of applied filters and finally using the array of filter apply the filter.

later you can remove filters referencing and removing items from the array and recalling the filter function. (up to your implementation....)

initiate an empty array at main scope as follows

```
let filters = []
```

apply the filters with this function:

```
function applyFilter(value) {
if(value)
 filters.push(':contains('+value+')')
}
```

then your filterData function:

```
function filterData() {
if (filters.length>0) {
    var rows = $("#shelulerData").find("tr").hide();
    var currentFilter = null;
    filters.forEach(filter => {
        if(currentFilter===null) {
        currentFilter = rows.filter(filter)
      } else
      {
      currentFilter = currentFilter.filter(filter)
      }
    })   
    currentFilter.show()
  }
}
```

Basically, you can chain filter functions to get the final filter so this is why i chained the `currentFilter` var in the loop and finally applied the `show()` function

[here is js fiddle with solution](https://jsfiddle.net/obgyxuhr/6/)

Comment: i try your sollution and chose *11* and *week* and this is filtering in bad approach

Comment: in case if i chosse one option its works, in multiple no

Comment: @Andrew you can inspect the final solution which meets your goals

Comment: It's working, but in case if i change options and tap button it's stop works

Comment: if you want to reset filters you could on tap of button do `filters=[]`

Comment: Need your Help same task